# Image in the middle of navbar

Tags: html, css, image, navbar, graphical-logo

I want to put an image in center of my navbar on my page. Here's my result wanted (example):

[image]

How to make it working (without bootstrap).

For now my code looks like this:

```
<nav class="navigation">
            <ul class="navigation-list-1">
                <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#add-info">Add info</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-list-item"><img class="logo" src="assets/LOGO.png"></li>
                <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#form">Form</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

And styling:

```
.navigation-list-item {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 15px;
border-top: 10px solid white;
margin-right: -5px;

}

.logo {
max-height: 5%;
max-width: 15px;
background: cornflowerblue;
border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;

}
```

But it looks terrible and doesn't work... Maybe it's better way to put two navbars (left and right) into the main navbar container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flexbox

> **But** it will only work if you are having odd number of children and image must be in the center.

In order to make it responsive, you should use either `%` or `vw`(view width)

Check the example, where I have used `vw`, and also removed margin to stick it to the top.

> **FYI**- The trigger is onclick, so Click on the image when it's loaded ;)

```js
function big() {
  var w = 5;
  var foo = setInterval(function() {
    if (w > 15) clearInterval(foo)
    w = w + 1;
    document.getElementById('logo').style.width = w + 'vw';

  }, 100);
}
```

```css
.logo {
  width: 2vw;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
}

.outer>p {
  flex: 1;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: blue;
}

.outer>p>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.outer>p .logo {
  flex: 1;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <div class="outer">
    <p class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></p>
    <p class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#features">Features</a></p>
    <p class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#add-info">Add info</a></p>

    <p class="navigation-list-item"><img class="logo" id="logo" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg" onclick="big()"></p>
    <p class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#form">Form</a></p>
    <p class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#team">Team</a></p>
    <p class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></p>
  </div>
</nav>
```

### Example with Unordered List `<ul>`

Just added flex property to `<ul>`

```css
.navigation-list-item {
list-style: none;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.logo {
  position:absolute;
  
width: 10vw;
left:calc(50% - (10vw/2) - (10px/2));
background: cornflowerblue;
border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;
}

ul{
  display:flex;
  margin-left:-40px;

}
li{
  flex:1;
  background:yellow;
  border:1px solid green;
  height:70px;
  line-height:70px;
  text-align:center;
}

li>a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="navigation-list-1">
    <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
    <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#add-info">Add info</a></li>
    <li class="navigation-list-item"><img class="logo" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6f4af2d2d158"></li>
    <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#form">Form</a></li>
    <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
    <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Added javascript just for better visual explanation

Comment: Thanks! I messed around with tags and seems it is working.

Comment: And... I can't make this navbar 'sticked' to the top. Theres a whitespace between the top ob browser edge and navbar. How to deal with it?

Comment: Last question... When I try to change <p> and <div class="outer"> to <ul> with <li> it does not format in the same way. How to make the same with unordered list?

Comment: It's fixed with `<ul>` and `<li>`. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You could center the whole unordered list?

```
nav ul {
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: But how to make the LOGO big enough? It's so tiny within the nav list.

Comment: Increase the width and the height in the CSS. You made it kinda small.